# flutter dart How to remove underscore _ for RegExp, \\W+ doesnt remove underscore?

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

How to remove underscore _ for RegExp, \W+ doesnt remove underscore? what do i need to add to additional remove _?

This expression doesnt remove _.

```
sentence.replaceAll(new RegExp("\\W+"),"").toLowerCase();
```

Comment: You want everything other than `_`. Isn't it?or only the word characters something like`[0-9A-Za-z]`

Comment: i need _ to be remove too.

Comment: Does [this](https://regex101.com/r/YPletW/4) help?You can see the substituted text in substitution tab..

Comment: yup its work with double \\ instead of \

Comment: That is the regex engine in which I gave. If you convert it to code strings of course you have to escape it.

Comment: alright thanks man! @Mandy8055

Answer (score 1):

here the correct answer:

remove _

```
sentence.replaceAll(new RegExp('[\\W_]+'),'').toLowerCase();
```

remove _ /

```
sentence.replaceAll(new RegExp('[\\W_\/]+'),'').toLowerCase();
```